# Force YouTube API upload_video.py authentication to open in external browser?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Following this example: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

I run on cygwin/ windows and after I prepared everything I call

```
python upload_video.py --file="/tmp/test_video_file.flv"
                       --title="Summer vacation in California"
                       --description="Had a great time surfing in Santa Cruz"
                       --keywords="surfing,Santa Cruz"
                       --category="22"
                       --privacyStatus="private"
```

and cygwin opens an ascii browser which cannot display the Google login page correctly (Javascript issues), so I have no way of logging in.

**Is there a way to force the login/ authentication to be done via an external browser?** (Google Chrome for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found at: http://www.cnx-software.com/2014/02/09/how-to-upload-youtube-videos-with-the-command-line-in-linux/
*** just add  --noauth_local_webserver to the call